# Can we convert the html version of top level site's master page to .master file for subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

My top level site has a `X-master` page and I want a new `Y-master` page for the Sub-Site which is a replica of `X-master` page with changes to be made. In designer I tried to copy paste the html version of `X-master` page from top-level site master pages folder to Sub-Site's master pages folder(in designer). But the copied `X-masterpage` html version is not being converted to `.master` page in Sub-Site master pages folder.

Comment: First clear the SharePoint version, which one you are using? If it is 2013 then are you copying the html master page file only? or .master file also?

Comment: @Pro.. Version 2013,copied only the html file.

Comment: Alright, then you need to edit properties of that copied file to generate the .master page file. You need to select Html Master page as its content type so .master page file will be generated automatically. Try that.

Comment: will try and get back @Pro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the master pages and page layouts need to stay at the root site.. Even if you plan to use them in subsites.. So if you make the copy of your existing Master Page, make changes and keep it in the root-site, it will be converted to .master file.

Now in the subsite, stop master page inheritance and you can select the new masterpage you created (it should be listed in the drop-down once checked-in and published)